# Trying to get value from array, drupal

Tags: php, arrays, templates, drupal, drupal-7

[image]

I am trying to get the value from the array below tried both

```
print $node->field_equiryform_custmessage[0][0];
```

and

```
print $node->field_equiryform_custmessage[0]['value'];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 7 field arrays are now wrapped with a language element (the `und` in your output above means undefined, as in undefined language).

You can access your field's value either using `und` as an array key or (preferably) use the `LANGUAGE_NONE` constant:

```
print $node->field_equiryform_custmessage[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

If you're running a multi-lingual system it would look more like this:

```
print $node->field_equiryform_custmessage[$node->language][0]['value'];
```

The latter might actually be the more future-proof way of doing this either way.